# What is the role of the Kaladan project?

Tags: international-relations, china, india, international, myanmar

The Kaladan project it seems is the one of the wonders taking place. However I really do not understand what is the point connect Myanmar with India for a route that will connect the main Indian country with the North-East. I admit it is a marvel in its own way as it connects the nation but what I really do not understand is what role does the project play in the concurrent scenario? Is it only for transportation of normal people or it has something more to do with it.

Comment: As written your question lacks a lot of context. One of which wonders? Which concurrent scenario? The project seems to cut the travel distance in half, by requiring port operations. This may or may not make travel faster and cheaper, depending on the handling expenses.

Comment: It is a $484 million (U.S.) multimodal transportation line from India to Myanmar. Basically a ferry/freight route with well improved seaports, plus some supplemental road and rail lines and pipelines catering to the sea route. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaladan_Multi-Modal_Transit_Transport_Project

Answer (score 2):

Improving transport links between the Northeast division of India with the rest of India has been a long term project of India. Originally India tried to persuade Bangladesh to allow for transport links including access to the port of Chittagong which is only 200km away from Agartawala, the capital of Tripura. However, Bangladesh has consistently refused.

This has motivated India to begin the Kaladan project which links the port of Kolkata in East India with that of Sittwe in Rakhine state of Myanmar, then further road transport links to Mizoram state in North East India. It will cut the length of travel by around 1300 km. The project also plans to build two hydroelectric dams on the Kaladan river.

It has everything to do with improving public infrastructure for ordinary citizens as well as improving regional cooperation between Myanmar & India.